# Cluster point of a sequence is limit of a subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

*Edited as suggested in the comments.*

---

> Prove that if $x$ is a cluster point of a real sequence $(x_n)_n$, it is a limit point of a subsequence of $(x_n)_n. $

Previous questions have already tackled this issue but I want to **be sure that the specific wording in the proof I came up with is okay**.

> Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} } $ be a sequence of real numbers.
>
> Assume $x$ is a cluster point of $(x_n)_n$.
>
> Then, $\forall \epsilon >0 $ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists m>n $ such that $d(x,x_m)< \epsilon$.
>
> Then we can construct a subsequence $(y_n)_n$ of $(x_n)_n$:
>
> - $y_1 \equiv x_{k_1}$ where $k_1 \equiv \min \{n>0: 0<d(x, x_n)<1 \} $
> - $y_2 \equiv x_{k_2}$ where $ k_2 \equiv \min\{ n>k_1 : 0<d(x,x_n)<d(x,x_{k_1}) \}$
> - for any $y_n$ with $n>2$, $y_n \equiv x_{k_n}$ where $k_n \equiv \min \{ n>k_{n-1}:0<d(x,x_n)<d(x,x_{k_{n-1}}) \}.$
>
> Note that $k_n$ is well-defined since the definition of cluster point guarantees its existence.
>
> Since by construction $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}, m>n, d(x,y_m)<d(x,y_n)$, it is the case that $d(x,y_n) \rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow0$.
>
> Therefore $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\forall n >N, d(x,y_n)< \epsilon$, i.e. $x$ is the limit point of the subsequence of $(x_n)_n$, $(y_n)_n$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What if $x_n = x$ for some $n$, then your construction doesn't work

Comment: Thanks!! Is it okay now? @Jakobian

Comment: Now it's ok. I'd go more explicit on why $d(x, y_n)\to 0$ though. Also, a sequence $(x_n)_n$ from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$  <- this doesn't make much sense. If you want to be more formal, sequence $x:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ or sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers would be better. But noone writes sequences as functions, even though they can be thought of as functions, so I'd advice using the second way of writing

Comment: Something like this? @Jakobian

Comment: A sequence can decrease without going to $0$, for example $(1 + 1/n)_n$. Thus $d(x, y_n) \to 0$ does not follow from $\forall m>n, d(x, y_m) < d(x, y_n)$. You need to choose the $y_n$ by a stronger condition that just that they are closer than $y_{n-1}$.

Comment: So, the subsequence I've constructed is not converging or is only that specific argument you've mentioned invalid? @PaulSinclair

Comment: There is nothing that guarantees your sequence converges. It may, or it may not, depending on the $x_n$ sequence you start with. The solution is to pick your $y_n$ so that they have to converge. The condition you used to pick the $y_n$ was not sufficient for this.